# building the ta-lib library fails with undefined references from libm.so

Tags: c++, finance, ta-lib

Trying to `make` the ta-lib library (ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz) I get the following error:

```
/home/me/ta-lib/src/.libs/libta_lib.so: undefined reference to `sinh'
/home/me/ta-lib/src/.libs/libta_lib.so: undefined reference to `sincos'
/home/me/ta-lib/src/.libs/libta_lib.so: undefined reference to `ceil'
...
```

for a large number of maths functions.

The failing command looks like this:

```
gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/ta_regtest (... .o files) -L/home/me/ta-lib/src \
    /home/me/ta-lib/src/.libs/libta_lib.so -lm -lpthread -ldl
```

The offending library (ta_lib) looks like this:

```
objdump -TC libta_lib.so | grep "    D  \*UND\*"
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              sinh
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              sincos
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              ceil
...
```

For the same maths functions (the grep excludes defined functions and those that have a "w" (presumably weak) flag)

A map lists the libraries included, among them:

```
LOAD /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
```

and a list of the symbols (objdump -TC) defined in libm.so includes:

```
000000000001a320  w  iD  .text  0000000000000020  GLIBC_2.2.5 ceil
```

which was one of the undefined references (they are all there). I cannot determine the meaning of GLIBC_2.2.5.

Why is the loader not finding these functions?

My system looks like this:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mynode 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Mine builds fine after `configure && make`. System is `Linux laptop 3.19.8 #1 SMP Thu May 28 20:44:58 SAMT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`